# Serializable casting and ahy its not preferable to make static variable serializable

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization, casting, static

A few questions:

1. When I do casting while reading an object.... why I have to use `B o_b = (B) one;` and why not `A o_b = (A) one`? Object type is `A` which I have saved in a file. Also, I want to confirm that when we make an object 
   like this  `A a =  new B()` what is object type in this line?
2. Moreover, why doesn't the class get saved using an object ?
3. Why it's not preferable to make static variables to be saved (serializable)?

Code:

```
import java.io.*;

class A {

    public void go(int height){
    }

}

public class B extends A implements Serializable{

    int height;

    public void go(int height){
        this.height = height;
        System.out.println("height is" + height);
    }



 public static void main(String[] args){
        A a = new B();
        a.go(43);
        //Saving Object 
        try{
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("foo.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
            o.writeObject(a);
            o.close();
           // Reading an Object
           FileInputStream filestream = new FileInputStream("foo.ser");
           ObjectInputStream p = new ObjectIntputStream(filestream);
           Object one = p.readObject();
           //Casting
           B o_b = (B) one;
           p.close();
           System.out.println("saved values were" + o_b.height);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use proper indentation.

Comment: Use proper grammar, spelling, and indentation and people might answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Lets look at what's the type at `A a = new B()` first. The static type of the variable `a` is `A` while the dynamic type is `B`. So while you use `a` as if it was of type `A` in your code it points to an object of type `B` at runtime. You might want to read up on polymorphism. This also explains why you can cast your deserialized object to `B` although you serialized `a`. The object that was acctually serialized was of type `B`. You could change your initialization of `a` to `A a = new A()` and the cast would fail at runtime. Also you should already be getting a compiler warning for an unchecked cast, which basically means it cannot be ensured that the cast suceeds at runtime.
2. You could also serialize so called class objects. With `Class<A> classA = A.getClass()` you would have get the class object for class `A` and would be able to serialize it.
3. You are serializing instances. A static variable is not part of an instances, it belongs to the class the instances where created from. I think you could serialize static variables by serializing the class object (see 2.) but I'm not sure about that.

I hope this answers your questions. Keep in mind that not everything that can be done should be done. I would consider serializing a class object bad design. There is certainly a better way to persist the content of static variables.